# CGAL: libQGLViewer error

Tags: cgal

I am trying to install the CGAL library as it is clearly explained in (https://www.cgal.org/windows_installation.html). However, I am failed when compiling the libQGLViewer. First of all, I could not find and download the libQGLViewer 2.3.17 version. I tried to compile both 2.3.1 and 2.3.2 version as it is explained in the guide but I got a bunch of error messages(ending with a fatal error). Error messages are mostly about undeclared indetifier and identifier not found. I tried to fix these error messages but every time resulted with failure.

Can you please help me about getting suitable version and installing the libQGLViewer? 
My final question is do I necessarily need this particular library for visualizing and analyzing (visualizing results of these analysis) point clouds?
I appreciate for helps

Comment: CGAL 4.4 is not compatible with the latest release of QGLViewer. Adding `#include <QGLViewer/manipulatedCameraFrame.h>` and `#include <QGLViewer/manipulatedFrame.h>` in `demo/Polyhedron/MainWindow.cpp` should fix the issue. The next release will however be compatible

Comment: @sloriot Your comment should be an answer. That would allow to close the question.

Comment: Thanks for answers I used version 2.5.1 and it works.

Answer (score 1):

CGAL 4.4 is not compatible with the latest release of QGLViewer. Adding `#include <QGLViewer/manipulatedCameraFrame.h>` and `#include <QGLViewer/manipulatedFrame.h>` in `demo/Polyhedron/MainWindow.cpp` should fix the issue. The next release will however be compatible